# Rails 4 - Custom Validation Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

This is my model -

```
class Leave < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :staff
validates :staff, :leave_type, :start_date, :end_date, :number_of_days, :approved_by, presence: true
enum leave_type: {Medical: 0, Annual: 1, Urgent: 3, "Birth Leave": 4}
validate :check_leave, :if => "self.number_of_days.present?"




protected

def check_leave
  if self.leave_type = 0
    if ( self.number_of_days + LeaveAllocation.last.medical_leave_counter ) > LeaveAllocation.last.medical_leave
      self.errors.add(:number_of_days, "Days exceeded the limit")
    end
  end
  if self.leave_type = 1
    if ( self.number_of_days + LeaveAllocation.last.annual_leave_counter ) > LeaveAllocation.last.annual_leave
      self.errors.add(:number_of_days, "Days exceeded the limit")
    end
  end

end

end
```

When I try to run the validation, it only seems checks the first one "0" even if i change the selection to "1". Any help would be appreciated! Thanks

Comment: On Create and Update, number_of_days is the field name (integer)

Comment: can you please post complete Model Class? @Sean Lin

Comment: Updated with complete model

Comment: `:if => "self.number_of_days.present?"` why double quotes required here?? @Sean Lin

Comment: It makes no difference whether it's single or double.

Answer (score 1):

change to `==` in if condition.

```
self.leave_type == 0 and
self.leave_type == 1
```

Comment: it won't validate after changing to == . If I use =, it validates but only the first one...

Comment: change this line like this `validate :check_leave, if: -> { self.number_of_days.present? }`

Comment: It's still the same..only validate the first step for "0"